# Can I change a variable with the "X" of the cycle for?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, cycle

I want to make a cycle for that changes part of the variable called "url".
I have tried this but doest work, any suggestion?

for x in range(1, 10):

```
url == 'www.mywebsite_begining_of_link/',x,'/year_end_of_link'
print (url)
```

Thanks a lot!

I want this output:

````
www.mywebsite_begining_of_link/2/year_end_of_link
www.mywebsite_begining_of_link/3/year_end_of_link
     ...
     ...
www.mywebsite_begining_of_link/10/year_end_of_link```
````

Comment: THis is simple concatenation of string variables, covered in any tutorial on strings.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try F-strings

```py
url = f'www.mywebsite_begining_of_link/{x}/year_end_of_link'
print (url)
```